# Listview changes focus when data changed

Tags: android, listview

Im currently working on a listview on android. is there a possible way that the focus wont change if the data from the listview changes?.
I got a listview that changes if there is a new data fetched from the server, i want to do is if the user scrollsdown the listview then a new data is fetched and added to the listview the listview wont change focus.

Here is a snippet on how i change the listview and update it.

```
                   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(lvGameViewLobby.getContext(),R.layout.custom_listview_style,R.id.custom_list,gameLobby);
               lvGameViewLobby.setAdapter(adapter);
               gameRoom.setCurrentGameLobby(gameLobby);
```

note that the data is fetch from the server on a loop so every time a data is change or a data is added it will clear the Arraylist and place the new fetched data from the server then place it in a list view.

Comment: which focus you want top or bottom focus

Comment: where ever is the user is scrolling to.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Pulltorefresh and Loadmore](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore)** listview for view and for update data after change use **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** method.